# Manipulating Windows Registry

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want every time my program runs make this process:

1- Check if there is a windows registry key called `"foo"`

2- If it not exists create with the value `10`

3- If it exists decrement its value

4- If its `value == 0` close de program

I know that i will use this functions, but i don't know how to use them:

```
RegCreateKeyA, RegSetValueExA
```

The function to create the key worked, but I can not to set the values and do not know how to do what I need.

```
HKEY key;

RegCreateKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"foo",&key);
RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"foo", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
RegSetValueExA(key,"bar",0,REG_DWORD,(LPBYTE)10,sizeof(10));
```

Comment: To query and set a value, you need to pass the address to the value to query/set. This is done by e.g. using the address-of operator `&` on a variable, *not* by casting a literal integer to a pointer (which results in the `RegSetValueExA` function trying to read the value from the *address* `10`, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). If you go to the [MSDN API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) and search for those functions you should be able to find good examples on how to use them.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of minimal research. Do you really think that there is no answer already exist to this original unique question? Please, next time [search StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481288/manipulating-windows-registry) and read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724182%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It's not appealing to try to help you write this code. You haven't got any error checking at all. Is this the first Win32 API you've ever called? Perhaps start with some simpler ones. Now, `(LPBYTE)10` is a pointer with address 10. Anything de-referencing that gets a seg fault. You also need to learn C first. Or C++. Whichever it is you are using, apparently you aren't sure. You need to know what language you are coding in. There's no real way that you will write this code any time soon. We'll have to do it for you. What's the point of that. You need to walk before you run.

Comment: I will change the question: How can I determine if a key exists?

Comment: You need to step back quite a bit and understand the basics first. You need to know what language you are coding in. You probably do. But the question is tagged with two different languages. You really need to learn about error checking. You need to understand why your cast is broken. All of that you have to be on top of before you can usefully code against the registry API, one of the more complex Win32 APIs.

Comment: Same answer, read the documentation.  I'll get you started, read the documentation for `RegOpenKeyEx`.  For your new question, the important part is "Unlike the `RegCreateKeyEx` function, the `RegOpenKeyEx` function does not create the specified key if the key does not exist in the registry."  So if you call `RegOpenKeyEx` and it fails the key may not exist -- you can check this by examining the error code at taking the appropriate action.

Comment: Now i can set the value, but i cant read.

Comment: You really, really need to read the documentation, all of the documentation, that is found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The function you are looking for is `RegQueryValueEx`.  Which if you have even taken a cursory glance through the documentation you should have seen.

Comment: There's just no helping you is there? You aren't interested in doing it right and learning the basics. If you don't do that you'll be stuck like this forever.

Comment: I do hope you retained a copy of the Registry before you started throwing knives at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
HKEY key;
DWORD disposition;

LONG lRet = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("foo"), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &key, &disposition);
if (lRet != 0)
{
    // error handling...
}
else
{
    DWORD value;

    if (disposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
    {
        value = 10;

        lRet = RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("bar"), 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&value, sizeof(value));
        if (lRet != 0)
        {
            // error handling...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD size = sizeof(value);

        lRet = RegQueryValueEx(key, TEXT("bar"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&value, &size);
        if (lRet != 0)
        {
            // error handling...
        }
        else
        {
            if (value != 0)
            {
                --value;

                lRet = RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("bar"), 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&value, sizeof(value));
                if (lRet != 0)
                {
                    // error handling...
                }
            }

            if (value == 0)
            {
                // signal app to terminate...
            }
        }
    }

    RegCloseKey(key);
}
```